# Generate unique IDs in non-unique columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider this table:

**ex_table**

```
| gid | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | v1  |
| 1   | v2  |
| 2   | v3  |
```

Notice that `gid` is the id-like column and not unique.
I want to be able to insert values into the table either by generating a unique `gid` or by specifying which one to use.

For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO ex_table (val)
  SELECT --....
```

Should generate a unique `gid`, while

```sql
INSERT INTO ex_table (gid, val)
  SELECT --....
```

Should use the provided `gid`.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Define `gid` as `bigserial`, and it should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want *to the letter* of what you say by using `overriding system` value and an auto-generated column.  For instance:

```
create table t (
    gid int generated always as identity,
    name varchar(255)
);
```

Then

```
insert into t (name) values ('abc');
insert into t (gid, name) overriding system value values (1, 'def')
```

will insert two rows with a `gid` value of `1`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fc139cc73c42ddfc42a416b75c9879a7) is an example.

Just one caveat:  Inserting your own value does not change the next value that is automatically generated.  So, if you manually insert values that do not exist, then you might find that duplicates are later generated for them.

Comment: oof, that caveat is a dealbreaker

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE table_name (
    gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table_name_id_seq'),
    name varchar);

ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq
OWNED BY table_name.id;
```

OR SIMPLY

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
    gid SERIAL,
    name varchar);
```

AND THEN TO INSERT

```
INSERT INTO fruits(gid,name) 
VALUES(DEFAULT,'Apple');
```